# How to obscure telephone number from database

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you obscure a telephone number that is retrieved from a database? I'd like users to be able to click a button and the telephone number appears.

So far it's hidden from the user until they click the button, but you can see the number fine in the source code.

Is there anyway to hide/muddle the number up (perhaps inject some characters?) on page load and clicking the button removes these characters?

Comment: you can print out something like xxx-xx-xx staticly.

Comment: You could just use ajax to get it, that way it's really not visible in the source at all. Another common way to obfuscate emails and phone numbers from bots is reversing the numbers/letters and using CSS text-transform to make it display in the correct order etc.

Comment: The best way would probably be to not retrieve the full number until the button is clicked, then retrieve it with an AJAX request.

Comment: Either way you are sending the number

Comment: Wow, three pretty neat suggestions! Thanks guys, I'll try the AJAX method, onclick and retrieve the number first!

Comment: Also: is clicking the button a formality/courtesy, or does it cause a postback to (for instance) accept some terms of use, etc? Or are you concerned with concealing it from spiders? The purpose matters; your current method may be "good enough."

Comment: The number is solely for the end user to contact the business and so I only want users to see the number. The main purpose is to hide it from possible malicious use (spiders etc).

Comment: Then you could consider displaying an image of the number. It hides it from bots, and users don't need to click anything to see it.

Comment: You can use any of the same methods mentioned in [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/235937/does-e-mail-address-obfuscation-actually-work)